# Cordova Show InterstitialAd on Click

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

I'm using appfeel cordova admob plugin.
https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

I want to show InterstitialAd on click function at my cordova apps. Normally with default options, InterstitialAd shows on my app starting. But must show InterstitialAd when button clicked.

My default options

```
admob.setOptions({
            publisherId: "xxxx-myidxxx", // Required
            interstitialAdId: "xxx-myidxxx", // Optional
            tappxIdiOs: "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-iOS-IIII", // Optional
            tappxIdAndroid: "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-Android-AAAA", // Optional
            tappxShare: 0.5,
            adSize: admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER,
            bannerAtTop: false,
            overlap: false,
            offsetStatusBar: false,
            isTesting: true,
            adExtras : {},
            autoShowBanner: true,
            autoShowInterstitial: false // Optional
});
```

I can call function this type

```
$( "#myButton" ).on( "click", function() {
           admob.requestInterstitial();
           admob.showInterstitialAd();
});
```

I'm trying to call function this type but it's not work.

How can i call function when button click?

Answer (score 1):

Please see here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/showInterstitialAd, there is a full example on how to show interstitials:

Basically what you do is start ads with `autoShowInterstitial: false`, `requestInterstitialAd` when device is ready, show this pre-loaded interstitial when click event happens and reload a new interstitial when the last one has been shown:

```
var isAppForeground = true;
var isInterstitialReady = true;

function onAdLoaded(e) {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
      isInterstitialReady = true;
    }
  }
}

function onAdClosed(e) {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
      isInterstitialReady = false;
      admob.requestInterstitialAd();
    }
  }
}

function onPause() {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    admob.destroyBannerView();
    isAppForeground = false;
  }
}

function onResume() {
  if (!isAppForeground) {
    setTimeout(admob.createBannerView, 1);
    setTimeout(admob.requestInterstitialAd, 1);
    isAppForeground = true;
  }
}

// optional, in case respond to events
function registerAdEvents() {
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoaded);
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdClosed, onAdClosed);

  document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

function initAds() {
  if (admob) {
    var adPublisherIds = {
      ios : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
      },
      android : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
      }
    };

    var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? adPublisherIds.android : adPublisherIds.ios;

    admob.setOptions({
      publisherId:          admobid.banner,
      interstitialAdId:     admobid.interstitial,
      autoShowInterstitial: false
    });

    registerAdEvents();

  } else {
    alert('AdMobAds plugin not ready');
  }
}

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
  initAds();

  // display a banner at startup
  admob.createBannerView();

  // request an interstitial
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Then in your button event:

```
$("#myButton").on( "click", function() {
    if (isInterstitialReady) {
        admob.showInterstitialAd();
    } else {
        // We do not have an interstitial ready, try to request a new one
        // It can be mainly because of 3 reasons:
        //   - Can't connect with Admob (i.e. no connectivity available)
        //   - Admob does not have available any interstitials at this moment
        //   - Not enought time between last requestInterstitialAd() and myButton.click()
        admob.requestInterstitialAd();
    }
});
```